# Controling eventual AppEngine datastory consistency during testing

Tags: google-app-engine, go, google-cloud-datastore, consistency

I have an AppEngine app written in Go, and I'm trying to improve my tests.

Part of the tests that I need to run are a series of create, update, delete queries on the same object.  However given that the datastore is eventually consistent (these aren't child objects), I am currently stuck using a `time.Sleep(time.Second * 5)` to give the simulated datastore in the SDK enough time for consistency to propagate.

This results in tests that take a long time to run.  How can I force something more like strong consistency for tests without rewriting my code to use ancestor queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while, but the method that I found that works well is to call the context as follows:

`c, err := aetest.NewContext(&aetest.Options{StronglyConsistentDatastore: true})`

Comment: Please note, that this method only works when using the "appengine" package, and not the newer "google.golang.org/appengine" package.  For that, the method is quite different and is clearly shown in the documentation.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the dev_server arguments.  You will see there is an option for setting the consistency policy.

```
 --datastore_consistency_policy {consistent,random,time}
                        the policy to apply when deciding whether a datastore
                        write should appear in global queries (default: time)
```

Notice the default is `time`, you want `consistent`

Comment: I can't seem to find anything on a datastore consistency policy for the Go SDK, only for the Python SDK.  Could you please give me a reference for the Go SDK?

Comment: Go uses the python development server, so you can use the flag specified by Tim. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/go/tools/devserver

Comment: In the go doc's it shows two ways of running the server one using goapp, and the other launching dev_server.py directly. You may find you can only use the policy argument if you start the dev_server manually.

Comment: Okay, I can see how I can change the consistency policy for the devAppserver, but I still don't see how I can use this to run my tests.  I run `goapp test ./...` to run my tests, but if I use `dev_server.py` I can't seem to find a way to use it to run tests.

Comment: I don't use go so I won't be much help, except to say that goapp serve will run the dev_appserver. I have no idea what goapp test will be doing.  Have a look at what it actually invokes. You may have to modify it to run the dev_server whith the appropriate arguments.

Comment: I couldn't find that arg on the python dev_server page, but it's mentioned in the changelog: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver

Comment: This argument is also mentioned in the output of `dev_appserver.py --help`